# Avoiding duplicates in MySql.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't figure a way to deny same user accounts in my php website, and it's hard for me to use other made code. I tried using *unique* in phpmyadmin but it gave me an error after it denied it. Here's the code:

```
<?php
include '../layout/header.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];


if($pass1 == $pass2){


    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $email = $email;
    $pass1 = $pass1;
    $pass2 = $pass2;      

    include '../DB/DB.php';

    $db = new DB;


    $db->__set('username','root');
    $db->__set('password','');
    $db->__set('dsn','mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login;');
    $db->conn();

    $aData = array();
    $aData[0]['users'] = $uname;
    $aData[0]['email'] = $email;
    $aData[0]['pass']  = $pass1;

    $db->dbInsert('vartotojai', $aData);

    Echo "<a href='../index.php'>Atgal</a><br>";

}else{
    die("sorry, your passwords dont match. <br />");
}


}else{

 $form = '
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br />
Confirm password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Registruotis" name="submit" />
 </form>';


echo $form;


}

Echo "<a href='../index.php'>Atgal</a><br>";


?>
```

Comment: You want to avoid creation of same user with same email ?

Comment: which column in your database you want to use as a reference to check the duplicate records, like email or something else?

Comment: I want to avoid creation of same usernames. They can have same email, but not usernames.

Comment: And the column is users. Because I want to reject same usernames only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to see if there is already a record in the table which uses the same username.

Using a query like:

```
SELECT [row] FROM [table] WHERE users=[username];
```

...replacing [row],[table],[username] with there respective values.
The way you do a SELECT query will depend on what library you are using for your $db

You then need to check if any records were returned in your result set.

```
if (!isset($resultSet)) { //therefore username is unique
    //insert user to database 
} else {
    //prompt 'user already exists'
}
```

EDIT: PDO Example

```
$db = new Db();
$db->bind("uname",$uname);
$query = $db->query("SELECT uname FROM [table] WHERE users = :uname");
if (!isset($query[0]['users'])) { //therefore username is unique
    //insert user to database 
} else {
    //prompt 'user already exists'
}
```

Comment: It's kinda hard for me to do this way. Because i'm using PDO and don't really understand how to use your query with my.

Comment: What PDO library are you using?

Comment: I'm using this one: http://pastebin.com/RK2A6Bgk. Can't really say which one is that. 
When i tried your code it gave me an error saying: Call to undefined method DB::bind()

Comment: No, I mean where did you get your DB.php file from?

Comment: I don't remember, because I have it for a long time

Comment: I can't help you unless I know how to do a SELECT query with your library

Answer (score 0):

The best and fastest way to do this would be by defining a constraint within your database schema UNIQUE, as you already mentioned trying.

The other way would be to simply select any records within your database with whatever field you want to be 'unique' and if it returns any record, it clearly is not unique, and your script should fail, otherwise, continue with whatever it is you are doing.

The SQL query could look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sakila.actor WHERE [parameter] LIKE '[WHAT YOU'RE TESTING]';
```

And if this query returns 0, then you're good to go, if it returns 1, then there's exactly one person with that parameter already in, if it returns greater than one, you already have duplicate values.

Comment: These errors are shown when I use unique and try to register with same username: http://imgur.com/QHJUREo

Comment: This is what you would expect to happen if you try to insert a duplicate value. All you need to do is to catch the exception, and if the exception is thrown, then you will know that something with that name or email already exists, and handle the exception, probably show an error message of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

first create a field name like id with unique auto_increment and check the following code

select * from tbname where uname='name' and password="password"

if this query returns null array this is not a valid user else it may have array value it's your site's user   , this process is also same for insert the new user to the db